# Where to find older versions of Android Support Library?

Tags: android, teamcity, android-support-library

I am setting up CI server using TeamCity and I get a Gradle bust where it cannot find an Android Support Library that one of the modules uses. This is the error:

```
##teamcity[buildProblem identity='-1301271058' description='org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3.|nSearched in the following locations:|n    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.pom|n    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.jar|n    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.pom|n    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.jar|nRequired by:|n    fe824d50e5881e7c:hellocharts-library:unspecified' type='gradleBuildProblem']
```

It seems it is unable to find a specified version of the support library on the machine (`support-v4:21.0.3`) and is trying to look in remote repos - but it's not there either. I can't find it in the SDK manager to install manually (only the most recent version is there) and I can't seem to find it by Googling it.

I tried updating the module to use a newer support library but its producing weird build errors.

I am not getting this error on my local machine - only on the TeamCity server. I did not have to install it separately on my local machine.

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open SDK Manager and install `Android Support Repository`.

After that you can find the support library in:

```
<sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/
```